# How to instantiate and populate Page<Object[]>

Tags: java, spring, junit

For my Junit test cases,I need to instantiate and populate

```
Page<Object[]> page;
```

Where Page is Spring class `org.springframework.data.domain.Page`

Can you please let me know, how to achieve that?

Comment: what is the problem with `Object[] obj = new Object[];` fill some value then `Page<Object[]> page = new Page(obj);`

Comment: @YCF_L ,Thanks for your response,but unfortunately,they(spring) have not provided such constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an implementation of Page you can use:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;

....

String[] strArray = new String[] {"foo", "bar"};
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(strArray);

Page<String[]> page = new PageImpl<>(data);
```

javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html

Comment: Thanks Zack,but it gives me Page<String>,but I am looking for Page<String[]>

Comment: The data needs to be instantiated with a List of arrays then. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the update Zack.It gives compile time error "Cannot infer type arguments for PageImpl<>"

Comment: Ahh, that is because your environment is not using 1.8 or higher. If you've created a new project in Eclipse, the default is 1.5. Please verify your JRE/JDK is 1.8 or higher. OR you can put the type parameters in:  Page<String[]> page = new PageImpl<String[]>(data);